# How to label for this prediction example Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, conv-neural-network

Inspired by the blog post http://blog.avenuecode.com/using-deep-convolutional-neural-networks-dcnns-for-time-series-forecasting-using-tensorflow-part-1
where a time series of electricity consumption is converted into image representation for prediction, I was wondering of a simple example of using the same concept of predicting the next value of the time series to build a puzzle game. However, the time series is represented as an image. The point I don't understand is what should be the labels/predictor output? Take for example, in the following code the image `A` is followed by `B` since `B` is generated from the next time instant after `A`. The objective is that the model should be able to arrange the images in sequence to build a puzzle.

Question1) During training what should be the labels? I will have several such images. Then, during testing I will jumble the sequence and the model should give me the correct order aka prediction of the next image. Is that even possible?

Question2) I have represented the image as gray scale. Is there a better visualization colorful way that makes more sense in discriminating visually rather than just the salt and pepper visualization?

Shall be extremely grateful for suggestions

```
clear all

data=100*rand(3000,1);
x1= data(1:1024);
img1=reshape(x1,32,32);
img11=double(repmat(img1,[1 1 3]));
imwrite(uint8(img11), 'A.jpg');

x2=  data(1025:2048);
img2=reshape(x2,32,32);
img22=double(repmat(img2,[1 1 3]));
imwrite(uint8(img22), 'B.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### So you want to perform predictions using a time-series?

Well, it doesn't really make a whole lot of sense to use images to represent time series data. What you really want is just the data point itself, not some visualization of the data point. There are neural networks designed to perform predictions from time-series analysis, and as far as I know none of them take images as input. What you really want is something called a Recurrent Neural Network (RNN). You may find [Long Short-Term Memory (LSTM) networks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/long-short-term-memory-networks.html) to be of particular value in your use case.

If you are honestly and truly stuck with images, I am not experienced enough to tell you what might be the best approach. However there is [research out there that appears to have done this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320195467_Classification_of_Time-Series_Images_Using_Deep_Convolutional_Neural_Networks). [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275970614_Encoding_Time_Series_as_Images_for_Visual_Inspection_and_Classification_Using_Tiled_Convolutional_Neural_Networks) is an additional example.

> 1. During training what should be the labels?

Well you would need some kind of encoding, your proposal of a an alphanumeric sequence should suffice; but it may be easier to use integers.

> Then, during testing I will jumble the sequence and the model should give me the correct order aka prediction of the next image. Is that even possible?

Sure, why wouldn't this be possible? But there is a problem with testing in this way, it's called Information Leakage. You really want to provide the classifier with a new image it hasn't seen from the original time series, and then see if it can predict where it falls in the sequence of images that it has seen (been trained on).

> I have represented the image as gray scale. Is there a better
>   visualization colorful way that makes more sense in discriminating
>   visually rather than just the salt and pepper visualization?

Looking at the tutorial you provided, the end result was a matrix of binary values (either a 0 or a 1). A black and white image is a natural choice to represent a matrix of zeros and ones. You took it one step further by going to greyscale and you are now using all `0 - 255` possible pixel intensity values achievable with the `uint8` datatype. What else could you do visualization wise? Well a lot, but not in terms of representing just the data matrix alone. If you were hoping to get an RGB image, it is the same process as the greyscale image just repeat for 3 channels (Red, Green, and Blue). However, in your problem domain I don't really see how to do this easily. For instance, what constitutes the red channel? What about the green, or blue? This tells me that your current visualization technique is probably a good choice.

Comment: thank you for your answer but few things are unclear. Could you please clarify? You suggested in the first point in your answer that time series forecasting using images is not the correct way, rather I should directly use the time series. However, in the second point you mention that it is possible for the model to recognize the image during testing. But if I do not encode the time series as images & train the model using these encoded images then how to test using images is unclear to me. If I were to use images basically I am comparing each pixel (which is the next value in time domain).

Comment: If I use LSTM, then it is a normal approach of using real valued time series prediction. SO, the suggestion/answer for point 2 is probably not applicable if I don't use images in the first place. The primary reason to use images is to use the powerful image classifiers or some other justification as done in the blog. But still I don't know how to predict using image encoded version of the time series.

Comment: @SrishtiM I would be happy to clarify. I don't want to go so far as to say that time series forecasting using images is not the correct way, it just isn't a very common approach. If you decide to use the the time series data itself (as a sequential series of vectors) you will find it easier to use already established existing methodologies such as the Recurrent Neural Network (LSTM). 

The second point in my answer was intended to address the your original question. I wouldn't recommend using images, but if all you are have are the images, the research papers I linked to might be helpful.

Comment: @SrishtiM If you don't encode the time series data as images, then you are correct. You no longer want to test the classifier with images. The testing approach is still very similar. You take your whole time series, chop it up into bits and withhold a portion of the time series during training. Then during testing you feed it a vector it hasn't seen yet and ask the model to predict where this vector would lie in the time series (based on what the model has already seen in the training phase).

Comment: @SrishtiM I understand that encoding the series as images opens up the possibilities of using a wider variety of neural network architectures. However, I would caution you that when such networks were designed, the creators did not have time series analysis in mind. Now, if we are talking about RNN's then the creators *did* have time series analysis in mind. That is all I was trying to say. I do not mean to discourage you from experimenting with a novel approach! Just be aware that traditionally, time series analysis is performed with RNN's.

Comment: @SrishtiM As to why time series analysis is performed with RNN's, this is because RNN's are designed to learn from previous as well as current information. CNN's by design, only "learn" during backpropagation (i.e. the data it was most recently exposed to in time series n-1). RNN's on the other hand often have LSTM units which can "remember" inputs from several time cycles ago. This is why they are traditionally preferred to CNN's for time series analysis.